# IndexError: list index out of range/ Facenet

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying out a face recognition program using Facenet algorithm. Everything works fine, good recognition but the program gets quit when I move my head fast with this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vf.py", line 122, in <module>
    if HumanNames[best_class_indices[0]] == H_i:
IndexError: list index out of range




  for H_i in HumanNames:
       if HumanNames[best_class_indices[0]] == H_i:
       result_names = HumanNames[best_class_indices[0]]
       cv2.putText(frame, result_names, (text_x, text_y),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,1, (0, 0, 255), thickness=1, lineType=2)
```

Comment: Give you a little hit: check out `best_class_indices[0]`. You're welcome.

Comment: its an array of an array. so it's correct. There is some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no value stored in HumanNames, and if that is the case, then it would make sense that acessing first item in the list would throw an error.

First you should check the size of the HumanNames array, and during the debug process, add this line:

```
print(len(HumanNames))
# The rest of the code from the example....
```